# Why is the result of -5/2 being printed as 0?

Tags: c

Can you tell why this statement in C gives 0 as output

```
printf("Hello %f",-5/2);
```

Whereas

```
printf("Hello %d",-5/2);
```

is giving output as -2

Comment: What is the type of output when two integers are divided?

Comment: This here: `printf("Hello %f",-5/2);` causes UB. Read the specifications of `printf()` in the C standard or read the man page of `printf()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Division of two integers produces a integer result (`int` in this case).  The `%f` format specifier expects an argument of type `double`.  Using the wrong format specifier for a given argument triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case gives you an incorrect result.

If you want a floating point result, at least one of the operands to `/` must have a floating point type, i.e.

```
printf("Hello %f",-5.0/2);
```